# Isn't the element of Iterator in for loop local scoped?

Tags: rust

I have a simple struct like below called **TopicTree**:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Default, Clone)]
// #[allow(dead_code)]
pub struct TopicTree {
    topic_name: String,
    child: Option<Vec<Box<TopicTree>>>,
    data: Option<Vec<String>>
}
```

And another struct called App which has an **impl** block as below:

```
struct App {
    // Topic Tree
    topic_tree_root:TopicTree,
}

impl App {
    pub fn parse_topic_to_tree(& mut self, topic: &str){
        let mut temp_node = & mut self.topic_tree_root;
        let mut found = false;
        for text in topic.split("/") {
            for item in temp_node.child.as_mut().unwrap() {
                if item.topic_name == text {
                    temp_node = item.as_mut();
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the code, rustc gives me this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `temp_node.child` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/pub/lib/app.rs:22:26
   |
22 |                 for j in temp_node.child.as_mut().unwrap() {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `temp_node.child` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

So my question is, isn't variable **item** local scoped? if it is not as so, how can I iterate over **temp_node.child** in a nested loop, it is necessary because **temp_node** is also **mutable**.

Comment: Why borrowing `temp_node.child` mutably if you don't change it?

Comment: You are already doing a mutable borrow of `temp_node` so the compiler is not letting you borrow `temp_node.child` because it can lead to race conditions.  Just get a mutable reference to the parent pointer and modify it as needed.

Comment: Note: you don't need `Vec<Box<TopicTree>>`, `Vec` is already an indirection.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov maybe it sounds stupid, IDK, but as I said, the **temp_node** itself is mutable and I need the  **item** to be mutable so I can put **item** in *temp_node** for saving the state of the tree traversal, I need the **temp_node** to be mutable because I need to be able to mutate in some cases.

Comment: There are different things, `temp_node` being mutable via `let mut temp_node` means that you can reassign it later. The compiler would have no problem with it. But also `temp_node` can have a type that is a mutable reference to some object, so that you can change the value that `temp_node` refers to currently. That's why compiler is complaining, and since you don't use this mutability in the program you've shown, you can change the code to immutable references `let mut temp_node = &self.topic_tree_root`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov you are right, I tried to ask only one question to respect the rules and because of that the code is not complete, but as I said, the **temp_node** needs to be mutable because later I need to make a change to **temp_node.child** and its requires mutability for **temp_node** or the compiler will say, **you can not borrow it as mutable because it is behind a & reference**.

Comment: @AhmadMansoori The compiler error "... behind a & reference" is a different error for different code. But my guess is that you have (useless) calls to `as_mut()` in there, which the compiler complained about and encouraged you to use mutable borrows (`&mut`). The `as_mut()` serves no purpose in your code. As I alluded to in my answer, `&mut` and `mut` are not the same thing and do not require each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the inner loop to execute, the compiler has to 1) create an implicit borrow on `temp_node` in order to 2) borrow `temp_node.child`,  in order to call `as_mut()` (which takes `&mut self`) and then bind the result to `item`. The lifetime of `item` depends on `temp_node` being alive, because of this borrow-chain.

In a subsequent iteration of the outer loop, a conflict occurs: If `temp_node = item.as_mut()` has executed, you need to mutably borrow `temp_node` in the `for item = ...` line. But it is already being borrowed to keep `temp_item` alive, which came from `item`, which came from `temp_node`... Here, the circular logic might become apparent: There can be no guarantee - as the code is written, notwithstanding that the data structure wouldn't support this - that `temp_node` and `item` end up being *the same object*, which would cause two mutable borrows on the same value.

There might be some confusion with respect to `mut` and `&mut` here. `temp_node` needs to be `mut` (as in `let mut`, because you change `temp_node`), but it does not need to be a `&mut` (as in "mutable borrow", because you are *not* modifying the data behind the reference).

Comment: looks correct, thank you. but the last part is not correct, because the **temp_node** does need to be a mutable reference so later I can use it to mutate its child.